# how subtracting fields by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to subtract 2 number fields, both fields have a mask in this format: 00.000,00

I do not have a 'submit' button, I would like to do it using onKeyPress

here is my code:

```
<label>FIELD 1:</label>
    <td width="80%">
       <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" size="15" onKeyPress="return(mascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" />
    </td>
<label for="valorDesconto">FIELD2</label>
    <td width="80%">
       <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" size="15" onKeyPress="return(mascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" />
    </td>
```

here is the result

```
<label>Resul:</label>
<input type="text" name="Resul" id="Resul" size="15" />
```

How can I implement another function that subtract both fields?

Comment: What is `mascaraMoeda`? You have to show that code otherwise we have no information.

Comment: So get the values and subtract it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy mascaraMoenda is my coinMask, its the function that returns the mask 00.000,00 for the fields

Comment: Please, convert your code to english, its just the MascaraMoeda (i imagine it is in PT-BR). It is just a tip i did that some time ago (write a class in PT-BR and post it) its hard for the others to help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#field1, #field2').on('keypress keydown keyup', function (event) {
    var difference = parseFloat($('#field1').val()) - parseFloat($('#field2').val());
    // do something with the difference
});
```

This will bind `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup` to each of your inputs and substract the value of the second one from the value of the first.

Comment: You should convert each of those values to numbers using parseFloat(). It won't matter here because subtraction forces the conversion automatically, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field in which you can put your result:

```
<input type="text" id="result" />
```

Then in your mascaraMoeda method add:

```
difference =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("field1").value.replace(".","").replace(",",".")) - parseFloat(document.getElementById("field1").value.replace(".","").replace(",","."));
document.getElementById("result").value = difference;
```

Comment: I'm getting NaN for all the solutions

Comment: Can you put above difference = ... an alert()? Please add alert(this.value) and post the result here...

Comment: I did! Im getting undefined, why? is there a problem with conversion ?